# Typing hint for a tuple of unknown size?

Tags: python

Using Python 3.9, I'm used to declaring a tuple as `t: tuple[A, B]`. However, I now have a `list[int]`, which is converted to a `tuple`. Obviously, the size of the list is only known at runtime. How do I declare a typing hint for the variable storing `tuple(some_list))`?

Comment: `tuple[int, ...]`

Comment: I closed as a duplicate

Comment: You cannot type hint a heterogenous, arbitrarily sized tuple. In general, arbitrarily sized tuples are a strange thing. They are meant to be used as [product types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type)

Comment: One thing you *can* do is use something like `tuple[Union[str, int, whatever], ...]` but that might now have the exact semantics you are hoping for

Comment: Another option is `tuple[Any, ...]` which will also probably not have the exact semantics you're hoping for; anything will pass...